# How to check the signal integrity of CAN lines?

Tags: can

Its a general question.I would like to know what to look for when testing CAN circuit on CANH and CANL lines.What are the issues that are common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CAN interface physical layer is specified by ISO 11898:

- Part 2: High-speed medium access unit
- Part 3: Low-speed, fault-tolerant, medium dependent interface

Usually, the testing procedures are defined based on that specification.

Answer (score 0):

Your common-mode needs to be reasonable, your waveforms need low or moderate reflection, your delta-voltage needs to be about 1 volt peak-peak
into 120 ohm || 120 ohm (or 62 ohm single--ended).

And have moderate edge-speeds; 1nanosecond is a problem, including FCC radiation.